how does complex continuity work?
I am wondering if $\lim_{z\to c} f(z) = f(c)\ \forall z\in\mathbb R, i\mathbb R$ implies $\lim_{z\to c} f(z) = f(c)\ \forall z\in\mathbb C$ and if so can someone provide a proof.
I don't know if the notation $i\mathbb R$ is normally used so just to clarify $i\mathbb R$ is the set of all numbers which can be represented as $ix$ where $x\in\mathbb R.$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If, for example, $c=1+i$ then there is no sequence $(z_k)$ in $\mathbb R$ or $i\mathbb R$ that converges to $c.$ I think that you mean $\lim_{t\to 0} f(c+t)$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} f(c+it).$

Is it only known that $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$? Then it's basically just a function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2.$ Is following a "horizontal" or a "vertical" line to the point enough to determine the limit in that case?

Limits in the complex plane work like in $\mathbb{R^2}$: the existence in some directions does not ensure the existence of the limit.
Consider $$f(z)={ \begin{cases} \left(\frac{z}{\bar z} \right)^2 = \left(\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}\right)^2 & \text{if } z\ne0 \\  1 & \text{if } z = 0\end{cases} }$$
Then $$\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} f(z) = \lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)} f(z) = 1 = f(0),$$ where $\lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} f(z)$ and $\lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)} f(z)$ denote the limits on the real and the imaginary axis respectively, but $$\lim_{(x,x) \to (0,0)} f(z) = -1 \ne f(0)$$ so the limit does not exist. I encourage you to evaluate the limits by yourself.

In the Gaussian plane $\mathbb R^2$ as a complex field, limits are taken along paths. 2d continuity means the limit is independent of the direction on radial rays reaching the limit point. In complex algebra this amounts to
$$\forall \alpha \in (0,2\pi) \quad f(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(z+ h ( \cos \alpha  + i \sin \alpha )) $$
The paths along real or imaginary directions have no special significance. This fact becames crucial for the definition of complex differentiability, producing the CR-equations as a definition, namerly, that analytic functions depend in $\mathbb R^2$ on $x+iy$ only, not on the separately independent pair $(x,y)$ or the other complex degree of freedom $\overline z = x-i y $

the reason I asked the question was because in the CR-equations arn't they based around the fact that its differentiable if and only if the limit along the real axis is equal to the limit along the imaginary axis or am i terribly misinformed?

@RobertBusch When using the Cauchy-Riemann equations you write $f(x+yi) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ with $u, v : \Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$. But then to conclude complex differentiability you ask: (1) $u$ and $v$ are real-differentiable (through any path) and (2) they satisfy the differential equations. So is not only limits along real and imaginary axis, by condition (1).

@jjagmath but arnt what the differentiable equations saying that the limit along the path along the real axis is equal to the limit along the imaginary axis I mainly get this knowledge from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6woD-gzom4

@RobertBusch You're focusing in property (2). Did you see property (1)?

@jjagmath ok yeah thats makes more sense now thank you
